# jQuery().each(). Выбор одного элемента, с разными ID/

Tags: jquery

Доброе время суток!
Есть форма, с 1 checkbox, 1 label, 1 input[text] в таком порядке, и всех по 3 (инпут текст скрыт, и выпадает в зависимости, от того выбран или нет чекбокс).
С помощью `.each` перебираю, но не могу выбрать нужный инпут, выпадают или все, или тот который задам через `.eq()`;
На codepen.io HTML форма и скрипт. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('form :checkbox').click(function(){
        jQuery(this).each(function(index, element){

            if (jQuery(this).prop('checked')){
                jQuery('input:text').show()
            }
            else {
                jQuery('input:text').hide()
            }
        }); 
    });
});
```

https://codepen.io/masteine/pen/ZyZBqP

Comment: ссылка codepen ведет на обновленный скрипт, который теперь не демонстрирует проблему

Answer (score 1):

В событие onClick добавьте функционал поиска элемента `input`, соответствующего обрабатываемому `checkbox`:

```
// Определяем ID чекбокса:    
var cbId = $(this).attr("id").replace("_check","");

// Находим соответствующий input
var input = $("#" +cbId +"_input");
```

[Исправленный код](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xreRew?editors=1111)

Однако рекомендовал бы обернуть блоки в div'ы, тогда поиск соответствующего инпута можно будет сделать более элегантным:

```
 var input = $(this).closest("div").find("input:text");
```

[Пример](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dRLNyN?editors=1111)